# Fetch the most viewed data in databases

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

I want to get the most viewed photo from the database but I don't know how I shall accomplish this. Here's my SQL at the moment:

```
SELECT * FROM photos AS p, viewers AS v
WHERE p.id = v.id_photo
GROUP BY v.id_photo
```

The databases:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo_filename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `photo_camera` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `photo_taken` datetime NOT NULL,
  `photo_resolution` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `photo_exposure` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `photo_iso` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `photo_fnumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `photo_focallength` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `post_coordinates` text NOT NULL,
  `post_description` text NOT NULL,
  `post_uploaded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `post_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkbox_approxcoor` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `viewers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_photo` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `date_viewed` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

The data in `viewers` looks like this:

```
(1, 85, '3892a0ab97d6ff325f285b27b847070f', '2012-06-21 22:49:25'),
(2, 84, '3892a0ab97d6ff325f285b27b847070f', '2012-06-21 22:49:25'),
(3, 85, '3892a0ab97d6ff325f285b27b847070f', '2012-06-21 22:49:25');
```

One single row from the database for `photos` to understand how the rows looks like in this database:

```
(85, 'P1170986.JPG', 'Panasonic DMC-LX3', '2012-06-19 18:00:40', '3968x2232', '10/8000', '80', '50/10', '51/10', '', '', '2012-06-19 18:45:17', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0')
```

At the moment the SQL only prints the photo with ID 84. In this case it's wrong - it should print out the photo with ID 85.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a SQL antipattern to use implicit joins.  Explicit joins are easier to maintain and are less subject to errors due to things like accidental cross joins. Implict joins were replaced 20 years ago. Why are you still using them?

Comment: 20 years ago?! O.o You kidding, right? I didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to use `order by count(*) desc`

Answer (score 0):

most viewed photo...
there are two approaches to this.

simple one:
add a field to the photo table that is a counter, and update that field everytime a photo is viewed.

hard one:
this will allow you to track views back to users.
make a new table that allows for user id, photo id and counter.

every time a user views a new photo it gets put in ther with counter one.
when he or she views it again increase the counter.

then build a complex query with group by and count(userid)
somewhat like:

```
SELECT photoid , count(photoid) as howmuch FROM photostats WHERE 1 GROUP BY photoid ORDER BY howmuch DESC
```